# Method not found JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean

I want to call a method from managedbean in jsf but I am getting the same error.Before I didn't get this error.Here is my method and calling in xhtml.

```
public String veriSil(Personel personel){
    msb.baglan();
    String sonuc="";
    String sql = "DELETE FROM jsfapp.personel WHERE ad='"+personel.getAd()+"' AND soyad='"+personel.getSoyad()+"'";
    try {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) msb.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        resultSilme = pstmt.execute();            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (!resultSilme) {
        sonuc += personelad + " " + personelsoyad + " silindi.";
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(sonuc));
        return null;
    } else {
        sonuc += "Silme işlemi yapılamadı!";
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(sonuc));
        return null;
    }

}
```

I called in jsf ;

```
<h:commandLink action="#{kmb.veriSil}" value="Sil"/>
```

I can not see an error.What is going wrong?

Comment: you have to pass Personel object as a parameter to method in your action.

Comment: Why do you need a parameter in your method ? I don't see it being used anywhere

Comment: Is Tomcat support calling a method with parameter?

Comment: It depends on Tomcat's version. You need EL 2.2 for that, supported out of the box by Tomcat 7. Otherwise, you can add the library by yourself and replace Tomcat's one.

Comment: How can I replace tomcat one.I have downloaded el 2.2.jar and added into the project.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are calling a method that expects an argument without specifiying the argument. Therefore the compiler cannot match your call to a method because the argument is part of the method's signature.

Comment: "the argument is part of the method's signature" what is that? I have to call method with paremeter,haven't I?

Comment: You have a Personel argument as part of the method, as Julian said. your commandLink is attempting to call kmb.veriSil with no arguments - thus not finding your method. Look at how you are accessing personel and see if your better of changing your action signature.